# How do I determine which DataView generated an event?

Tags: events, slickgrid, dataview

I'm implementing filtering via the HeaderRow of my grids, and I've run across a problem I can't seem to solve.

All the examples that show dataView Event handlers employ global variables to identify the related grid, such as in:

```
gridQMsgsDataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(rowCountChanged);

(...elsewhere...)

function rowCountChanged(e, args) {
    grid.updateRowCount();   //'grid' is a global variable assigned to a slickGrid.
    grid.render();
}
```

Unlike in the examples that I find, I'm creating slickjGrids and dataViews dynamically at runtime, and keep their reference variables in a list as I create them.

I can't tell at compile time how many there will be, thus I can't use something like the global "grid" variable to reference the relevant dataview and/or slickgrid.

So I have two questions, and appreciate any insight:

when my rowCountChanged handler is called...

A) How do I know which dataView generated the event?

B) Once I know that, how do I know which slickgrid that dataView is associated with?

Answer (score 0):

**A)** `rowCountChanged` is invoked in the context of the dataGrid; so `this` is the dataGrid in your callback, or use the same closure describe in B)

**B)** Use a closure, which works even if multiple grids (displays) are bound to the same dataView (which is only possible because dataView is *not* associated with a particular Grid).

When you create the grid using the dataView (or assign it later), in the same scope (in which `grid` is available), subscribe to the callback using a helper function to enclose the grid:

```
function watchRowCountChanges(grid, dataView) {
  dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    grid.updateRowCount();   // `grid` is a _local_ variable
    grid.render();

    console.log(grid.name, this === dataView); // true story, use either!
  });
}

// elsewhere...

var grid1 = new Slick.Grid(element1, dataView, columns1, options1);
grid1.name = 'grid1';
watchRowChanges(grid1, dataView);


var grid2 = new Slick.Grid(element2, [], columns2, options2);
grid2.name = 'grid2';
grid2.setData(dataView);
watchRowChanges(grid2, dataView);
```

And when the row count changes:

```
grid1 true
grid2 true
```